# Не могу понять условия задачи?

Tags: c++

**Во общем не как не могу понять в чём заключаются условия задачи, пожалуйста объясните условия и как это можно сделать на с++**
[image]

Comment: А что тут непонятно? Циклом по i = 0; i < n*n; ++i идем и смотрим - сначала знак элемента a[i][i], а в зависимости от него считаем то или иное. Или вы хотите готовый код, чтоб вам только принести и сдать? :)

Comment: @Harry Что то не так) Если n = 10, то последнее значение i = 99. a[i][i]?

Comment: @EOF Да, описался - массив из n элементов, а я на автомате кинул n*n... `i< n*n` читать как `i<n`... Спасибо за поправку.

Comment: Да не мне не нужен код только объяснение условий

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понял задачу, покажу на примере:
Есть двумерный массив -

```
-1  2  2  1
 1 -1 -2  1
 2  1  0  2
-1 -1 -1 -1
```

Смотрим на первую строку: если у нас отрицательный элемент на главной диагонали, то считаем от первого элемента до первого отрицательного в этой строке. Ответ: 0

Смотрим на вторую строку: если у нас неотрицательный элемент на главной диагонали, то считаем сумму от первого неотрицательного элемента после элемента главной диагонали до конца. Ответ: 1

Смотрим на третью строку: на главной диагонали неотрицательный элемент, считаем сумму от первого неотрицательного элемента после элемента главной диагонали до конца строки. Ответ: 2.

Смотрим на четвертую строку: элемент главной диагонали отрицательный. Считаем сумму между первым элементом и первым отрицательным числом. Ответ: 0.

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас попробую